# Tell SAS not to produce scientific notation

Tags: sas

[image: output]SAS returns sci-notation in proc means sum output which I can't use for further rate calculation procedures. How to suppress SAS to produce sci-notation, any idea? Thanks in advance.

*"There's a prob solved similar but not quite applicable to this very case. I apologize if I missed correct way to modify that answer though".*

```
data non.test;
input year racecat outcome grand_total;
datalines; 
1995    1   1585    9988998
1995    2   268     9966565
1996    2   1574    5569885
1996    2   230     2366558
1997    1   1482    3366998
;
run; 

proc sort data=non.test;
by year racecat;
proc means data=non.test noprint;
 var outcome grand_total;
 class year racecat;
 output out=non.test(where=(year ne . and racecat ne .) drop=_type_ _freq_)
              sum(outcome) = by_outc
              sum(grand_total)=Grand_total;
run;
```

[image: rate is not calculate]

Comment: I don't see any issues with the code you posted. Can you show the error message or output that you want to be different.

Comment: Hi Tom, non.test is the header of my data where i am counting and i just posted proc means output where SAS produced grand_total in sci-notation.

Comment: The underlying data is present and you CAN use it for further calculations, your statement is incorrect. Scientific Notation only affects the appearance of the number, not the actual value.

Comment: Hi Reeza, you're right. I figured that i had typo in the variable name in the ensuing calculations. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to see the values display in a different format than the default `BEST12.` then change it with a FORMAT statement.

```
proc print data=non.test ;
  format grand_total comma20.;
run;
```

If you assign the format in the initial dataset then PROC MEANS will also assign it to the derived field in the output dataset.